# .h5ファイルのローカルでの実行方法

Tags: tensorflow

Google Colaboratoryで作成したモデルを.h5形式で保存し、MacBookのターミナル上で呼び出して実行しようとしておりますが、Web検索で調べてもやり方が良く分かりません。是非教えてください。

Comment: 質問文の「モデルを.h5形式で保存」とは、Colaboratory内で保存したということなのか、ローカルにダウンロードして持ってきたことなのか分からなかったです。どちらでしょう？

Comment: ローカルにダウンロードして持って来ております。別の方がご回答頂きました。有難うございます。

Answer (score 0):

ターミナル上で `python --version` を実行してバージョンがあっているか確認してみてください。

もしあってなければ、以下の手順でそれぞれインストールしてみてください。

- 「Homebrew」をインストール
- 「Homebrew」を用いて「pyenv」をインストール
- 「pyenv」を用いてPythonをインストール

そのあと、tensorflowとkerasをインストール（colabとバージョン合わせたほうがいいです）
すれば、使用できるようになると思います。

Comment: 有難うございます。試してみます！